# Laravel nesting where clause (Query Builder)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

So i am confused on laravel nested queries.
I am trying to prepared a search function that filters the products that is in the `sales_agreement` table but also if the record has financing i want it to be filtered too. 

Below is my sample.

(1) Table Products

```
        id         product_name         price
         1           car                 500k
         2           jeep                200k
         3           motor               100k
         4           bicycle             5k
```

(2) Sales Agreement

```
        id         product_id         price        financing
         1           2                 500k           BPI
         2           1                 200k           MetroBank
         3           3                 100k
```

Expected Output In my query

```
       product_id            product_name
          2                      jeep
          1                       car
          4                      bicycle
```

My Query

```
  $result = DB::table('products')
        ->whereNotIn('id',function($q){
            $q->select('product_id')->from('sales_agreement');
        })->where('product_name','LIKE','%' . $get['q'] . '%')
        ->select('id','product_name')
        ->get();
```

This filters all of the products that is not in the sales_agreement table. But i also want to consider the items that has a Financing record in the sales_agreement table. In that point i dont have an idea how to do it.

Any comments/suggestion/answer will be much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Do you have product model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try where null

```
    $result = DB::table('products')
    ->whereNotIn('id',function($q){
        $q->select('product_id')->from('sales_agreement')
          ->whereNull('financing');
    })->where('product_name','LIKE','%' . $get['q'] . '%')
    ->select('id','product_name')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude the products that don't have financing record you can do a left join with additional clause

```
$result = DB::table('products as p')
            ->leftJoin('sales_agreement as s', function ($query) {
                $query->on('p.id', '=', 's.product_id')
                      ->whereNull('s.financing');
            })
            ->whereNull('s.product_id')
            ->where('p.product_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $get['q'] . '%')
            ->select('p.id', 'p.product_name')
            ->get();
```